# Which is better: one large relation or three smaller relations with associations?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have to do a PHP website with an SQL database that stores jobs info. Currently we use an Excel sheet with about 30 columns that are subdivided in three catgories: basic job info, job review and job technical review. There are thousands of records in this Excel so I want this to be as optimized as possible.
My question is how should I model this: one huge relation with 30 attributes or three smaller relations (one for each category) and their corresponding associations to link them? Or maybe other way? The queries will almost always ask for all the information.

Thank you!

Comment: 1000s of records is still very tiny for a database. Is your 30 attributes likely to grow? Are you going to be quering for those with specific attribute values? Do a structure and then write the SQL queries you are going to need. If the query writing is hard/horrible then you've got the wrong structure.

Comment: @danblack the amount of attributes is not likely to grow. Both data models (huge table or few smaller tables) feel like hell to query but maybe the big table is easier (less joins).

Comment: @matsrom theoretically speaking, one should follow the rules for a normalised relation. But there are benefits of having a denormalised relation, rightly as you said, while querying. Only you can take that call, if your queries are extremely complex and slow then denormalisation may help, otherwise you should keep the tables seperate, as that is the essence of a "relational" database. Mind that you dont need to keep them all seperated or all together, you can reach a middle ground as per convinience and performance.